# Need help to figure out an approach to cluster data that I have

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, data-science, bigdata

I have data of a country with some numeric and nominal attributes

They are Company Name, Employee Count, Sales Volume, Company Type.

I want to figure out what type of company has better Sales Volume and if employee count effects  to make a company sell more.

As there is no definite level, and as I am novice to Machine learning, I am not confident and I think it is unsupervised learning and needs clustering, but can't figure out the approach to start.
Appreciate your help. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a target variable, don't use clustering.

Instead, use **regression**.